# Partial sum of ${A \choose i} {B\choose n-i}$, when $B=-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

It's easy to see that 
$$ \sum_i {A\choose i} {B\choose n-i} = {A+B\choose n} $$
since when we choose $n$ things out of $A+B$, some ($i$ of them) are in the $A$ and the rest are in the $B$.

- Is there any reasonable formula for
  $$ \sum_{i< I} {A\choose i} {B\choose n-i} = {A+B\choose n}, $$
  i.e. we have a bound on how many of them are from the $A$ side?
- Is the $B=1$ case any easier? (That being my real question.)

EDIT: I totally misasked this question, and have hopefully fixed it here: [Partial sum over $M$, of ${m+j \choose M} {1-M \choose m+i-M}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40741/partial-sum-over-m-of-mj-choose-m-1-m-choose-mi-m)

Comment: Did you mean $B=1$ in the title?

Comment: For $B=1$, maybe you want to take a look at [Pascal's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).

Comment: The formula holds for all integer $i$. (According to Knuth in *Concrete Mathematics*)

Comment: In the first question, you didn't mean to include the right-hand side, did you?

Answer (score 1):

For B=1 this is rather easy:

${1 \choose j}$ is $1$ if $j$ is $0$ or $1$, and is $0$ for any other value of $j$.  So your first expression becomes $ {A\choose n-1} {1\choose 1} + {A\choose n} {1\choose 0} = {A+1 \choose n} $ 
or as Fabian says, Pascal's rule

$$ {A\choose n-1} + {A\choose n} = {A+1 \choose n}. $$

Your second expression depends on $I$.  If $I \le n-1$ then it gives a sum of 0; if $I = n$ and $i \lt I$ it give a sum of  ${A\choose n-1}$, and if $I \gt n$ it gives a sum of ${A+1 \choose n}$.