# Partial sum over $M$, of ${m+j \choose M} {1-M \choose m+i-M}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there (likely to be) any formula for
$$  \sum_{m' \geq m} {m+j \choose m'} {B - m' \choose m+i-m'}  $$
?

I am mainly interested in the case $B=1$ (or a prime power), if that's any easier.

EDIT: as suggested, here are the $B=1$ answers for $m=0\ldots 4$, $i,j< 10$,
arranged as matrices (one for each $m$).

$m=0: \begin{pmatrix}{2}&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1\\
{2}&
{2}&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1&
1\\
0&
0&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
{-1}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
1&
{-2}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
{-1}&
{3}&
{-3}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
1&
{-4}&
{6}&
{-4}&
1&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
{-1}&
{5}&
{-10}&
{10}&
{-5}&
1&
0&
0\\
0&
0&
1&
{-6}&
{15}&
{-20}&
{15}&
{-6}&
1&
0\\
0&
0&
{-1}&
{7}&
{-21}&
{35}&
{-35}&
{21}&
{-7}&
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$m=1: \begin{pmatrix}{2}&
{2}&
{3}&
{4}&
{5}&
{6}&
{7}&
{8}&
{9}&
{10}\\
0&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
{-1}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
1&
{-2}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
{-1}&
{3}&
{-3}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
1&
{-4}&
{6}&
{-4}&
1&
0&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
{-1}&
{5}&
{-10}&
{10}&
{-5}&
1&
0&
0&
0\\
0&
1&
{-6}&
{15}&
{-20}&
{15}&
{-6}&
1&
0&
0\\
0&
{-1}&
{7}&
{-21}&
{35}&
{-35}&
{21}&
{-7}&
1&
0\\
0&
1&
{-8}&
{28}&
{-56}&
{70}&
{-56}&
{28}&
{-8}&
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$m=2: \begin{pmatrix}{2}&
{3}&
{6}&
{10}&
{15}&
{21}&
{28}&
{36}&
{45}&
{55}\\
{-2}&
{-2}&
{-6}&
{-10}&
{-15}&
{-21}&
{-28}&
{-36}&
{-45}&
{-55}\\
{2}&
1&
{7}&
{10}&
{15}&
{21}&
{28}&
{36}&
{45}&
{55}\\
{-2}&
0&
{-9}&
{-9}&
{-15}&
{-21}&
{-28}&
{-36}&
{-45}&
{-55}\\
{2}&
{-1}&
{12}&
{6}&
{16}&
{21}&
{28}&
{36}&
{45}&
{55}\\
{-2}&
{2}&
{-16}&
0&
{-20}&
{-20}&
{-28}&
{-36}&
{-45}&
{-55}\\
{2}&
{-3}&
{21}&
{-10}&
{30}&
{15}&
{29}&
{36}&
{45}&
{55}\\
{-2}&
{4}&
{-27}&
{25}&
{-50}&
0&
{-35}&
{-35}&
{-45}&
{-55}\\
{2}&
{-5}&
{34}&
{-46}&
{85}&
{-35}&
{56}&
{28}&
{46}&
{55}\\
{-2}&
{6}&
{-42}&
{74}&
{-141}&
{105}&
{-112}&
0&
{-54}&
{-54}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$m=3: \begin{pmatrix}{2}&
{4}&
{10}&
{20}&
{35}&
{56}&
{84}&
{120}&
{165}&
{220}\\
{-4}&
{-7}&
{-20}&
{-40}&
{-70}&
{-112}&
{-168}&
{-240}&
{-330}&
{-440}\\
{6}&
{9}&
{31}&
{60}&
{105}&
{168}&
{252}&
{360}&
{495}&
{660}\\
{-8}&
{-10}&
{-44}&
{-79}&
{-140}&
{-224}&
{-336}&
{-480}&
{-660}&
{-880}\\
{10}&
{10}&
{60}&
{95}&
{176}&
{280}&
{420}&
{600}&
{825}&
{1100}\\
{-12}&
{-9}&
{-80}&
{-105}&
{-216}&
{-335}&
{-504}&
{-720}&
{-990}&
{-1320}\\
{14}&
{7}&
{105}&
{105}&
{266}&
{385}&
{589}&
{840}&
{1155}&
{1540}\\
{-16}&
{-4}&
{-136}&
{-90}&
{-336}&
{-420}&
{-680}&
{-959}&
{-1320}&
{-1760}\\
{18}&
0&
{174}&
{54}&
{441}&
{420}&
{792}&
{1071}&
{1486}&
{1980}\\
{-20}&
{5}&
{-220}&
{10}&
{-602}&
{-350}&
{-960}&
{-1155}&
{-1660}&
{-2199}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$m=4: \begin{pmatrix}{2}&
{5}&
{15}&
{35}&
{70}&
{126}&
{210}&
{330}&
{495}&
{715}\\
{-6}&
{-14}&
{-45}&
{-105}&
{-210}&
{-378}&
{-630}&
{-990}&
{-1485}&
{-2145}\\
{12}&
{26}&
{91}&
{210}&
{420}&
{756}&
{1260}&
{1980}&
{2970}&
{4290}\\
{-20}&
{-40}&
{-155}&
{-349}&
{-700}&
{-1260}&
{-2100}&
{-3300}&
{-4950}&
{-7150}\\
{30}&
{55}&
{240}&
{519}&
{1051}&
{1890}&
{3150}&
{4950}&
{7425}&
{10725}\\
{-42}&
{-70}&
{-350}&
{-714}&
{-1477}&
{-2645}&
{-4410}&
{-6930}&
{-10395}&
{-15015}\\
{56}&
{84}&
{490}&
{924}&
{1988}&
{3520}&
{5881}&
{9240}&
{13860}&
{20020}\\
{-72}&
{-96}&
{-666}&
{-1134}&
{-2604}&
{-4500}&
{-7569}&
{-11879}&
{-17820}&
{-25740}\\
{90}&
{105}&
{885}&
{1323}&
{3360}&
{5550}&
{9495}&
{14840}&
{22276}&
{32175}\\
{-110}&
{-110}&
{-1155}&
{-1463}&
{-4312}&
{-6600}&
{-11715}&
{-18095}&
{-27236}&
{-39324}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Have you calculated any examples to see if there are any patterns?

Comment: Yes, and I did, but not enough to guess an answer. Examples added.

Comment: Although I don't know if your summation is handled by the methods in the following book, you might want to check it out.  The methods here are often called "revolutionary" as regards summations of binomial coefficients: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Comment: It seems you are using the notation ${n\choose k}$ outside of the range $0\le k\le n$. What numbers does it denote?

Comment: ${a\choose k} = a(a-1)\cdots (a-k+1)/k!$ for $k\geq 0$, so ${-n\choose k} = (-1)^k {k+n-1\choose k}$.

Comment: Here is a quite comprehensive source of similar-looking identities:  http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF